# Numbers appended to column names when reading CSV in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to open the file using this link https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00529/diabetes_data_upload.csv and I need to use the pandas library to determine the type of each column in this table using numpy and write the resulting column types to a separate csv file.

So I wrote the code

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

link = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00529/diabetes_data_upload.csv"
table = pd.read_csv(link, skiprows = [0])#skip first row

result = table.dtypes
print(result,'\nAll results has been saved to results.csv file')
result.to_csv('results.csv')
```

If I open result.csv I got next info:

```
,0
40,int64
Male,object
No,object
Yes,object
No.1,object
Yes.1,object
No.2,object
No.3,object
No.4,object
Yes.2,object
No.5,object
Yes.3,object
No.6,object
Yes.4,object
Yes.5,object
Yes.6,object
Positive,object
```

But I expected that the output should be

```
40,int64
Male,object
No,object
Yes,object
No,object
Yes,object
No,object
No,object
No,object
Yes,object
No,object
Yes,object
No,object
Yes,object
Yes,object
Yes,object
Positive,object
```

It is clear that ,0 - it's because while opening the file we get an 'id' row
But why instead of just 'No' we get 'No.2'?
Can somebody explain what am I did wrong?

Comment: I think the numbers are appended to differentiate row values as they are not unique. An `Yes` can belong any of the column that contain `Yes` in it's values. You can apply a text processing layer to remove the numbers.

Comment: Why use `skiprows` here? You are cutting off the first row, which contains the labels for each column. I think your read_csv call should look like `table = pd.read_csv(link)`

Answer (score 1):

The suffix is due to `mangle_dupe_cols=True` option of [`pd.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) but you can't change the value to `False` (`ValueError: Setting mangle_dupe_cols=False is not supported yet`)

So, try

```
names = dict(zip(table.columns, table.columns.str.split('.').str[0]))
table = table.rename(columns=names)
result = table.dtypes
result.to_csv('results.csv', header=False)
```

Content of `results.csv`:

```
40,int64
Male,object
No,object
Yes,object
No,object
Yes,object
No,object
No,object
No,object
Yes,object
No,object
Yes,object
No,object
Yes,object
Yes,object
Yes,object
Positive,object
```

Comment: It seems that the OP also wants to remove the `.2` from `No.2`.

Comment: @DrShams. Does it solve your problem now?

Comment: So, it was due to the duplicate values. Thanks for the update!